# set measurable iff characteristic function is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $X$ be a measurable space. If $E$ is measurable set in $X$ and if
>
> \begin{equation}   \chi_{E}(x)=\begin{cases}
>                   1, & x\in E \\
>                   \\
>                   0, & x\notin E.
>  \end{cases} \end{equation}
> then $\chi_E$ is a measurable function.

That's fine because :
$\mathcal{X}_E^{-1}(A) =\begin{cases}
X, & 0,1 \in A \\
E, & 1 \in A, 0 \notin A \\
E^C, & 1 \notin A, 0 \in A \\
\emptyset, & o.w.
\end{cases}$

What about the other inclusion? If the indicator function is measurable, A is in the Sigma algebra.
I thought to use the counter image of 1A, but i don't know what to put inside to show that.

Comment: $\{1\}\subset \mathbb R$ is measurable.

Comment: $A=\chi^{-1}(B)$ whenever $B$ is a Borel measurable set with $1\in B$ and $0\notin B$. Choices enough. Just pick one out.